# Javascript Showing and Hiding Numbers Each Second

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

here's what I managed to do:

```
<div class="numbers" id="numbers">
            <div id="11" hidden="">
          <img src="numbers/11.png">
      </div>
            <div id="12" hidden="">
          <img src="numbers/12.png">
      </div>
            <div id="13" hidden="">
          <img src="numbers/13.png">
      </div>
            <div id="14" hidden="">
          <img src="numbers/14.png">
      </div>
            <div id="15" hidden="">
          <img src="numbers/15.png">
      </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function numbers() {
        var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (15 - 10 + 1)) + 10;
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var enddate = document.getElementById("end_date").value;
        var datetime =  (currentdate.getUTCMonth()+1)  + "/"
            +  currentdate.getUTCDate() + "/"
            + currentdate.getUTCFullYear() + " "
            + currentdate.getUTCHours() + ":"
            + currentdate.getUTCMinutes() + ":"
            + currentdate.getUTCSeconds();
        var date2 = new Date(enddate);
        var timestamp1 = datetime.getTime();
        var timestamp2 = date2.getTime();
        if(timestamp1 > timestamp2)
        {
           //kill the interval
           //kil the timer
           //show the winner

        }
        else
        {
            $("#numbers").hide();
            //hide all  numbers
                          $("#11").hide();
                                $("#12").hide();
                                $("#13").hide();
                                $("#14").hide();
                                $("#15").hide();
                                //show generated new numbery
              $("#"+num).show();
              $("#numbers").show();
        }

 }

    setInterval("numbers()", 1000);

</script>
```

It's not Working... I tried adding an alert message in the function(numbers) and it still not working..
I used PHP to generate those numbers, I pasted the HTML output of the script..
Would Love to hear about fixing this script :)
thank you.

Comment: Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. Specifically the last line (1\000?) looks suspicious, but there might be other problems too.

Comment: *"It's not Working"* is not a useful problem description.

Comment: `setInterval(numbers(), 1\000);` remove slash from `1\000`

Comment: I swear I made this script two days ago, and I Really want to learn from my mistakes, not trying to be a douche or something..

Comment: No-one is saying that, but you need to be more specific than just dump the code here and say "it doesn't work". Tell what errors you get, what it's supposed to do and what it does instead.

Comment: @AmitSoni I did, Uploaded to my host and still the same result...

Comment: @Juhana the problem is not from the Slash!

Comment: Where is this div with id end_date??

Comment: it's up here is it: `<input type="hidden" id="end_date" value="<?php echo $end_date_js?>"/>`

Comment: Start debugging by putting console logs; e.g. first line in numbers: console.log('numbers');, in timestamp1 > timestamp2: console.log('1 > 2'), in else: console.log('else'); or something even more meaningful ;-) (also watch out for the "debug console" if you not already did)

Comment: @fast there's a problem with "datetime.getTime" :(

Comment: @user3554384 see my update below :-)

Answer (score 0):

In the line:

```
setInterval(numbers(), 1000);
```

numbers() is actually executed instead of beeing scheduled to execute each second. Try this:

```
setInterval("numbers()", 1000);
```

---

Your datetime is a string, right? Maybe you mixed it up with currentdate; try:

```
currentdate.getTime();
```

Note that getTime() is UTC-based; so there should be no need to convert the currenttime to UTC anyway. Also i'd expect you can compare the Date objects directly, without going over 'getTime' (not sure, though..).

Comment: Already Did but no luck :( thanks for the answer Will be careful next time ;)

Comment: I added an alert(1); into the first line of the function, it kept alerting each second! I opened the console on my firefox it said "TypeError: datetime.getTime is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

My answer: 
first thanks to fast because the setinterval function was not working at all until he explained!
second, there was an Error that made the javascript code to die SO I replaced:

```
    var date2 = new Date(enddate);
    var timestamp1 = datetime.getTime();
    var timestamp2 = date2.getTime();
```

With:

```
    var date1 = new Date(datetime);
    var date2 = new Date(enddate);
    var timestamp1 = date1.getTime();
    var timestamp2 = date2.getTime();
```